# Converting a specifically formatted string to number in matlab

Tags: matlab

How would I convert the formatted string '1234+06' to a number in matlab? I understand how to convert a string to a number, so should I just delineate with the plus sign? What if someone sends me a file in the future that doesn't use plus signs? I'm going to try:

```
pos = fscanf(fid,'%s',1);
C = strsplit(pos,'+')
first_num=C(1);
second_num=C(2);
pos=first_num*10^second_num;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to be more precise... What does the plus sign indicate? Is it an addition that has to be calculated or just a character inside the numbers that can be omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string almost has Matlab's scientific notation; only an  `e` is missing. So: insert that `e` before a `+` or `-` sign if preceded by numbers (not before a possible leading sign) using [`regexprep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html), and then call [`str2num`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html):

```
>> str = '1234+06';
>> str2num(regexprep(str, {'(?<=\d)+', '(?<=\d)-'}, {'e+', 'e-'}))
ans =
   1.2340e+09

>> str = '-1.2-3';
>> str2num(regexprep(str, {'(?<=\d)+', '(?<=\d)-'}, {'e+', 'e-'}))
ans =
   -0.0012
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str2num('str')
```

Will only work if the format is one of the one formats specified [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html)

I would go through the string and remove the + sign and then convert from there.

I would use the [regexprep](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) function.